# How to find which version of Microsoft.NETCore.App is executing using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my application on the health page I would like to know what is the Dot net core runtime used to host the application.

We have `Environment.Version` but it only shows, something like this.

```
{4.0.30319.42000}
Build: 30319
Major: 4
MajorRevision: 0
Minor: 0
MinorRevision: -23536
Revision: 42000
```

Is there a way I can come to know what is the version of the ASP.NET Core used along with minor version like 2.2.3?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully below code should work:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(t);
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fvi.FileVersion;
```

Where:  `t is typeof(sometype from Microsoft.NetCore.App assembly)`

Comment: It does not give version like 2.2.3 it gives file version which is 2.2.2.19024

Comment: Above code gets file version and not assembly version.  Probably you need assembly version.  Can you try assembly.GetName().Version and check if it works ?

Comment: That does not provide the right answer as well it give something like this 2.2.2.19024